# setup caldav specific for ios devices

Tags: ios, synchronization, caldav

I am trying to configure [Baikal calDAV](http://baikal-server.com/) server to sync contacts on my IPhone/IPad.

But so far I did not succeeded in doing that. Every time it tells me that the settings were not verified.

I tried configuring:

`http://mydomain:12026/cal.php` in the phone but nothing worked. Is this the correct way?

The settings work in google rest console plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After careful consideration and try and fail/success scenarios, I concluded that:

1. `http://mydomain:12026/cal.php`

   url should be redirected to `http://mydomain:12026/`
2. Usually the above move can be done with a .htaccess file with:

> ```
> RewriteEngine on
> RewriteRule ^ cal.php [L]
> ```

This will redirect all traffic and cripple your admin/index.php page from baikal.